# How to read and handle multiple lines which belong together?

Tags: c#, dictionary, streamreader

I am reading a file with a `StreamReader`. Now I want to read the cotent into a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

The file that I read looks like this:

```
'someKey'
Value1someKey
'anotherKey'
Value1another Value2anotherKey
```

I am at the point where I get the keys with following code

```
reactionInfo = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
string line;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   if (line.Trim().StartsWith("'"))
   {
      List<string> values = new List<string>();
        if(!reactionInfo.TryGetValue(line,out values))
        {
          reactionInfo.Add(line, new List<string>());
        }
    }
 }
```

How can I map the values of the next line to the key that is in the line above?

Comment: How consistent is the data, is it "always" key first list/data second?

Comment: Is anything stopping you from reading two lines (the pair: key and values) and iterate over reading two lines instead of one line?

Comment: Are the keys always unique?

Comment: Jeah its always like the example above, we have a Key between `'` and in the next line at least one Value and the Values are seperated by spaces. 

What stops me from reading two line is the knowledge how to reading two lines at ones :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a copy of your last read key, then use it to add the values in the next line.

```
reactionInfo = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
string line;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    var lastKey= "";
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       if (line.Trim().StartsWith("'"))
       {

            if(!reactionInfo.ContainsKey(line))
            {
              reactionInfo.Add(line, new List<string>());
              lastKey = line;
            }

        }else
            {
              reactionInfo[lastKey].AddRange(line.Split(' ').ToList());
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: I stick with the idea, but with the else-case needs to be with the outer if-statement because now you always look for lines with `'` at the beginning, my Values dont have this at the start of the line

Answer (score 1):

Read the next line in the loop to add those values while adding entry into dictionary. The below lines read the next line which can be added while adding.

```
var valuesStrings = reader.ReadLine().Split(' ');
```

**Full Code:**

```
reactionInfo = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
string line;
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       if (line.Trim().StartsWith("'"))
       {
            List<string> values = new List<string>();
            if(!reactionInfo.TryGetValue(line,out values))
            {
              var valuesStrings = reader.ReadLine().Split(' ');
              reactionInfo.Add(line, values.Length > 0 ? new List<string>(new List<string>(valuesStrings)) : new List<string>());
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

**Additional Suggestion :**

Wrap the StreamReader into using block.

Comment: I would move the StreamReader into a using-Block. Just to support good practices.

Comment: Sure, that's the right way of using StreamReader. I will update my answer for additional suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: This works fine for me, thanks. Btw because its c# you need to call values.Count instead of length and there is a small typo where u wrote stirng instead of string :D